# Header and sub header to be inserted between the records without using SQL cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, cursors

Below is the employee table

**| emp_id |  emp_name |  emp_type | emp_status | course attended |**

---

1                   AAA              On Roll              'A'                         2

2                   BBB            Contractor             'A'                         4

3                   CCC              On Roll              'I'                         1

4                   CDS            Contractor             'I'                          7

5                   Ada              On Roll              'A'                         2

6                   BfB            Contractor             'A'                          2

---

with this i need below output without using cursor

Column1    Column2
 ***On Roll***         5
  **-Status 'A'**   4
      AAA          2
      AdA           2
  **-Status 'I'**     1
      CCC         1
 ***Contractor***   13
  **-Status 'A'**   6
      BBB         4
      BfB           2
  **-Status 'I'**     7
      CDS         7

I need all the headers, sub headers and emp name in same column.

Comment: THis is not a job that can be done easily in SQL, it is better to do in the application code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select emp_type, emp_status, course_attended, 1 as order1, 1 as order2
from employee e
union all
select emp_type, emp_status, sum(course_attended), 1 as order1, 0 as order2
from employee e
group by emp_type, emp_status
union all
select emp_type, '' as emp_status, sum(course_attended), 0 as order1, 0 as order2
from employee e
group by emp_type

order by emp_type, emp_status, order1, order2
```

Comment: I'm looking for tree like structure as i show.I need all the headers, sub headers and emp name in same column.

Answer (score 0):

What ever output format you have asked is bit difficult in SQL. BUt you can try something below and then re structure the results based on your requirement in PLSQL.

```
SELECT EMP_TYPE ||'--'||EMP_STATUS||'--'||EMP_NAME,SUM(COURSE_ATTENDED) FROM
(SELECT 1 EMP_ID ,'AAA' EMP_NAME,'On Roll' EMP_TYPE, 'A' EMP_STATUS, 2 COURSE_ATTENDED FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ,'BBB', 'Contractor' , 'A' , 4 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 'CCC' , 'On Roll', 'I' , 1 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 'CDS' , 'Contractor' , 'I' , 7 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 , 'Ada' , 'On Roll' , 'A' , 2 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 , 'BfB' , 'Contractor' , 'A' , 2 FROM dual)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((EMP_TYPE),(EMP_TYPE,EMP_STATUS),(EMP_TYPE,EMP_STATUS,EMP_NAME));
```